# MVC ASP Problema con Validacion Required

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hola consulta tengo un modelo sin dataanotation REQUIRED , pero la vista me genera una validacion , existe alguna propiedad NOTREQUIERED [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha llegado a pasar.
Intenta actualizar tus librerías de jquery, jqueryval y jquery unobtrusive.

También si no tienes en ese modelo ningún required, podrías eliminar el llamado a jqueryval en tu vista y/o el `Html.Validation`

Comment: acabo de actualizar las librerias y elimine las validacione en las vistas y continua el problema , requiere que queden nulos

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de tu vista en tu pregunta?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tel4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

Comment: esa es la vista del telefono

Comment: @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Comment: las variables que no sean string deben de quedar con el tipo? para que sea opcional